# RxJava loop in android

Tags: rx-java

I have a UserBean like :

```
class UserBean {
    public List<String> userNumber;
    public int userId;
    public String userName;
}
class UserBeanData {
    public String userNumber;
    public int userId;
    public String userName;
}
```

Now , i want to circular this bean list and get a piece of data list,like this :
[{userId , userName , userNumber},{userId , userName , userNumber},...].
The way I use it now is:

```
    List<UserBean> userBeen = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<UserBeanData> userBeanDatas = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable.from(userBeen)
            .flatMap(new Func1<UserBean, Observable<UserBeanData>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<UserBeanData> call(UserBean userBean) {
                    return Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(userBean), Observable.from(userBean.userNumber)
                            , new Func2<UserBean, String, UserBeanData>() {
                                @Override
                                public UserBeanData call(UserBean userBean, String s) {
                                    UserBeanData tData = new UserBeanData();
                                    tData.userId = userBean.userId;
                                    tData.userName = userBean.userName;
                                    tData.userNumber = s;
                                    return tData;
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<UserBeanData>() {
                @Override
                public void call(UserBeanData userBeanData) {
                    userBeanDatas.add(userBeanData);
                }
            });
```

Are there any other better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap` can take a second argument as result selector (which help to combine results)

`flatMapIterable` transform a list to an `Observable` with items from the list. As `flatMap`, `flatMapIterable` can take a result selector

```
final List<UserBeanData> userBeanDatas = Observable.fromIterable(userBeen)
        // emit all numbers and create a UserBeanData for each, using the bean as source 
        .flatMapIterable(bean -> bean.userNumber, (source, number) -> new UserBeanData(number, source.userId, source.userName))
        // transform the observable as a list
        .toList()
        // get the list
        .blockingGet()
```

Please note that this code targets RxJava 2 but should work with RxJava 1 (change `Observable.fromIterable` to `Observable.from` and `blockingGet` to `toBlocking().first()`

Comment: Thank you very much . Through your method I completed this demand

Comment: I want to filter the number of 15 userbean,so tried that:

    `Observable.from(userBeen)
              .flatMapIterable(userBean -> userBean.userNumber,(source, number) -> 
              { // if number is "15" return source else return null;})
              .filter(source -> 
              {// if source != null return true,else return false})
              .toList()
              .toBolcking()
              .first();`

This is the worst way is it?

Comment: don't change `flatMapIterable`: just filter if source.number != 15. You'll alocate an object that may be filtered just behind, but I think that the overhead is minimal.